# LabelEncoding for Train and Test Data separately

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

Dataset needed label encoding to deal with non-numerical values. But train and test data have a few values which are not mutual. So as expected I got this error "y contains new labels: ". How to fix this issue and do label encoding ?

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Your test data contains some labels which are not present in your training data. These are useless as your model was never exposed to these values hence has not learnt anything from them.

There are 2 approaches to solve this :

1. Create 1 hot encoding using `pd.get_dummies` and drop columns which are not present in test data.
2. Drop the variable itself.